# for loop in shell

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu

This is a homework I have for my Operative Systems class...
This program sums all the digits from a number and returns the sum e.g. 123  1+2+3 = 6 
I have an error in the for statement, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong... please help!

```
#!/bin/sh
read number
len=${#number}
cont=0
for(( i = 0 ; i < $len; i++ )) 
do
     cont=expr `$cont + number%10`
     number=`$number / 10`
done
echo "$cont"
```

Terminal gives me the error ./ej.sh: 5: Syntax error: Bad for loop variable

Comment: What version of bash?  did you try using `#!/bin/bash` ?

Comment: Shell languages are very sensitive to whitespace. Don't forget, you are executing commands, not C-ish functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) write the shebang as /bin/bash

2) you don't need the dollar sign in the expression

3) you should wrap the entire expr in backticks

```
#!/bin/bash
read number
len=${#number}
cont=0
for (( i = 0 ; i < len; i++ )); do
     cont=`expr $cont + $number % 10`
     number=`expr $number / 10`
done
echo "$cont"
```

Comment: Good idea to use `$()` instead of backticks: easier to nest, and easier to see.

Comment: don't even need the `expr` :)

Comment: @ghostdog74, yes, you can do something like `((cont=cont + number % 10))`.  I merely wanted to highlight the key issues with the original code

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention whether its purely `bash` or not..

```
$ echo "1234"|sed 's/\(.\)/\1+/g;s/\+$//' | bc
10
```